# What is the difference between debug and trace on a ARM based SoC?

Tags: arm, trace, ds-5

ARM DS-5 IDE talks about separate debug and trace features. I am an app developer, who is not used to these terminologies for ARM devices.

Can someone explain what is the main difference between trace and debug on ARM based SoC and when would you use each of them?

Comment: There's not really anything ARM-specific about this unless you want to get right down into fiddly specific details. Broadly, from the app-level perspective, debug lets you see what state things are currently in; [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_%28software%29) lets you see you how they got there.

Comment: This is where I get confused. In all other IDEs, you get to see the call stack during debugging. From your defn of trace, call stack is part of trace and not debug! Let me put the question other way, what can I do with trace for target program that one cannot do with host program with typical host IDE.

Comment: Ah, subtlety - the debugger reads the _current_ value in the SP register, looks at the _current_ contents of that memory and unwinds what it thinks are (and usually are) stack frames. I guess you've not yet had the pleasure of debugging a returning-into-a-corrupted-stack-frame crash where the debugger shows complete nonsense, wishing you had a log of everything that actually executed from which you could pick out exactly when and where previously the bad write happened ;)

Answer (score 0):

In ARM Architecture (also in general), debugging divides into 2 modes.

1. Invasive Debug
2. Noninvasive Debug

Invasive debug is similar to what you do when you debug a desktop application. CPU (Program execution) halts, you see the CPU/Program stack and can modify it

Noninvasive debug means you are not stopping cpu/program execution, you are only observing it hence can't modify it. "Trace" falls into this type of debug mode(noninvasive).

For more information: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0433/c/debug/debugging-modes